# Can anything be done to improve the speed of a Salesforce Communities pages

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aggregateresult

I have couple community pages which takes about 10-15 seconds to load data. There are few aggregates quires running behind the pages to fetch data. Other pages is fine as they have only one query on each page.

Is there anything can do to improve performance of aggregate queries?

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend that you pinpoint the exact performance problem that you're encountering before assuming that the aggregate SOQL queries are the problem area.

Salesforce has a chrome plugin that is currently in Developer Preview, and is [documented in the Summer '17 Release Notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer17/release-notes/rn_networks_performance_tool.htm), which should assist you in locating where the bottlenecks are in your lightning pages.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-community-page/alkcnclapbnefkodhbkpifdkceldogka

> **Salesforce Community Page Optimizer**
>
> **Analyze, debug, and improve the performance of your Lightning application (Developer Preview)**
>
> The Salesforce Community Page Optimizer (Developer Preview) analyzes
>   your lightning based community/apps and identifies performance
>   optimization opportunites. Use the information to refine your design
>   and improve performance for your members.
>
> Installation and usage of this extension is covered by the EULA:
>   https://secure2.sfdcstatic.com/assets/pdf/misc/salesforce-community-eula-ofs-page-optimizer.pdf